# Building with Multiple Unit Testing Frameworks?

Tags: jquery, .net, unit-testing, frameworks, asp-classic

I have a .NET solution that works together with some classic ASP pages, as well as some T-SQL stored procedures. I also have a product built with web technologies: JQuery, HTML5, CSS 3. What I need is to install unit testing frameworks for these products in such a way that I can run a build against all of these at once, and get a single unit test execution across these frameworks.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, wouldn't a build scripting tool like NAnt or MSBuild work ? You'd have one script invoking multiple tasks.. one for each different test runner.

Comment: Ooohh ... I think you are right! Thanks, Gishu. I'm thinking NAnt would be my best choice here since I'll be using XUnit type frameworks. Would you mind posting this as an answer, instead of a comment, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A build scripting tool like NAnt or MSBuild should do the job.

You'd have one script invoking multiple tasks.. one for each different test runner. Most unit test frameworks have console runners which integrate nicely with the build tools.

Answer (score 2):

Thing about unit testing is you really needed to have considered unit testing *before* building the product.  Introducing unit testing into an existing system is anywhere from very very difficult to impossible.  I very much doubt that commercially the cost would ever pay itself back.

You would be better off re-writing the code with TDD approach and using modern test friendly languages (like not using asp-classic).  Something like ASP.NET-MVC is what you are looking for the server-side code and [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) for jquery based code (I haven't used QUnit so I can't vouch for its efficacy).

Comment: Unfortunately, not doing it is not an option for me. So, I've got to figure out how to make it work :)